# Program is not executing the content correctly

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with the following function of mine where I am unable to get the `if (sequence[i]!='M' && sequence[i]!='U' && sequence[i]!='I')` works..

Basically, my programs works in this procedure -

1. Enter in the size of the input
2. Enter in the character sequence where the characters can only be M, U or I

For example. If I enter in `3` as my input size, followed by `MUUI`, it will print as invalid input and ask for a new input until something like `MUI` is inputted.

However, if I enter in `3` as my input size, followed by `MPO` as the character sequence, the program will continue to run the line `if (sequence[i]!='M' && sequence[i]!='U' && sequence[i]!='I')` even though it is not right.

And if I tried rearranging my lines, while the input characters are correct this time, the size will be incorrect and the program will still continue on to execute..

Am I doing it wrong somewhere?

```
int main(){
int sz;
cout<<"Enter in size of input: ";
cin>>sz;
char *sequence = new char[sz];
cout<<"Enter MU character sequence(M/U/I): ";
cin>>sequence;

bool checkMUI =isMUString(sequence, sz);
while(checkMUI== false){
    cout<<"INVALID INPUT. RE-Enter MU character sequence(M/U/I): ";
    cin>>sequence;
    checkMUI =isMUString(sequence, sz);
}

bool isMUString(char* sequence, int size){

    int numberOfChars = 0;
    while (*sequence != '\0')
    {
        numberOfChars++; sequence++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if (numberOfChars != size){
            if (sequence[i]!='M' && sequence[i]!='U' && sequence[i]!='I'){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: You might want to use a `switch` statement here instead of a convoluted chain of `&&` operations.

Comment: Also why are you re-writing `strlen`? It's really confusing what you're doing here, and also unclear why this is tagged C++ when it's all C code.

Comment: Also at the point you start with the for loop, `sequence` is already pointing to the end of the string.

Comment: @tadman, I am working in C++ hence the tag. And as for why I am not using `strlen`, I have not yet taught on using that..

Comment: If you're working in C++ I'd strongly recommend using `std::string` instead of C-style strings with NULL terminators. They're usually a lot safer to use in practice and way less error prone. Also don't be afraid to read the documentation on the Standard Library to see what tools are available to solve your problems before writing your own solution.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure why my school/lecturer is not using `std::string`.   And I have been taught in this way for the past 2.5 months

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
bool isMUString(const char* sequence, int size) {
    int numberOfChars = strlen(sequence);
    if(numberOfChars != size) {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if (sequence[i]!='M' && sequence[i]!='U' && sequence[i]!='I'){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's what I changed:

- Use strlen to determine the length of the string
- Take `if(numberOfChars != size)` out of the for loop body because it only needs to be checked once.

Here's an example, if you don't want to use `strlen()` (altough you should). I make a copy of the `sequence` pointer, so that you still have a pointer to the beginning of the string when you're done with the counting while loop:

```
bool isMUString(const char* sequence, int size) {
    int numberOfChars = 0;
    const char* ptr = sequence;
    while (*ptr != '\0')  {
        numberOfChars++; ptr++;
    }

    if(numberOfChars != size) {
        return false;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if (sequence[i]!='M' && sequence[i]!='U' && sequence[i]!='I'){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work in my cause, unfortunately I have yet to learn `strlen` or anything to do with `#include <stdio.h>` or `#include <string.h>` Just curious though, is there anything that I can change from my current code?

Comment: `strlen()` is a function that counts the characters in a string.

Comment: Ah now I understand your question. If you don't want to use `strlen` you have to make a copy of the `sequence` ptr and use that for counting. Otherwise you don't have a pointer to the beginning of the string anymore. I updated my solution.

Comment: Your solution is about the same the the one posted by @AnmolSinghJaggi and it will give me the same problem too, where it keeps prompting me to re-input of the character sequence even if `the numberOfChars` equals to `size`

Comment: Okay, it does works... Something seems to be doing weird when I tried re-compiling in my `.o` file and it did not work, unless I gave a new name or deleted it and run again

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
bool isMUString ( char* sequence, int size )
{

    int numberOfChars = 0;
    while ( sequence[numberOfChars] != '\0' )
    {
        numberOfChars++;
    }

    if ( numberOfChars != size )
    {
        return false;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( sequence[i] != 'M' && sequence[i] != 'U' && sequence[i] != 'I' )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and it is failing :( Suppose my first input is wrong eg. MPO, then I re-enter in as MUI, it seems to be returning as false, I say this because in my main function, there is this line `bool checkMUI =isMUString(sequence, sz); while(checkMUI== false)` and it keeps asking me to re-enter

Comment: Show the complete `main()` function in the question text.

Comment: I have just included in the part used in the main() function only

Comment: This is weird.. It is working now that I re-compile while giving it a different output name.. Can I ask what is the difference between the `while` loop you have used as compared to mine?

Comment: No difference in the working of that loop. But in your case, the `sequence` pointer got incremented meaning it was not usable again in the next loop.